# How to show all users of all databases in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I know `show users` or `db.getUsers()` can show all users in current database in mongodb, but how to list *all users in all databses* for ease of management as an administrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find information about all users in all databases in `system.users` collection of `admin` database. See MongoDB documentation for [system.users](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-users-collection/) collection.

Answer (score 1):

> I know show users or db.getUsers() can show all users in current
>   database in mongodb, but how to list all users in all databses for
>   ease of management as an administrator?

I would like to say that, i am not discarding anything of @Saleem.
To showing the all users in mongodb, suppose that if you have a GUI connection of mongodb with their client tool. you can also able to see all users in the mongodb database (System database as well as user databases). In my environment i have `Robomongo` mongodb third party client tool, through which i have connected mongodb with `localhost` and by default `port` of `27017`.

You just connect the `mongodb` with `Robomongo` client tool. For showing all the users in mongodb the steps will be as follows:

**Method 1:**

1. Expand your connection, Click on `System` folder.
   [image]
2. After clicking on System folder, by default you shall get `two
   databases`(`admin` & `local`) like this way

[image]

**Note:** In my case i have already created the user databases like (MyFirstDB,Zubair,haidar,test).

3. Expand the `admin` database, Go to `collections` folder then click
       on `System` folder. Within the System Folder there will be there
       `metadata` files like that
4. system.indexes
5. system.users
6. system.version

[image]

4. Right click on `system.users`, some of the options will appear in
   the new window. Among them choose the `view Documents`.

[image]

After that automatically the `mongo shell` will be open like as

[image]

As you can see the above mongo shell window under the key column . There is three users like

test.haidar (Here `test` is database and `haidar` is user)

test.vijay (Here `test` is database and `vijay` is user)

Haidar.skant (Here `Haidar` is database and `skant` is user)

you can see here the command like

```
db.system.users.find()
```

through which you shall find out the `all users` in the mongodb.

**Method 2:**

After connection the `mongodb` through `Robomongo` client tool.Expand the connection click on `System` folder then right click on `admin` database.
[image]
open the mongodb shell through the option like 'open shell'. The mongodb shell will be open . just type there the query like

```
db.system.users.find()
```

[image]

Execute the query through `F5` or Execute button of the Robomongo client tool.
And you shall get all users in the mongodb.

**Note:** In my conversion i have discuss about `Robomongo` client tool. It's third party freeware software tool, you can find out [Here](https://robomongo.org/download) and [Here](http://www.npackd.org/p/robomongo/0.8.4). In my conversion i have used Robomongo 0.8.4.

Hope this will help out to you , for finding the all users in mongodb users.

Comment: How is that different from simply executing these commands on the shell (except displaying them on robomongo)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use admin
db.system.users.find({}, { db: 1, user: 1})
```